# On Amiga, what happens when I write to $DFC5A0 by mistake?

Tags: hardware, amiga

I'm fixing a game (TV Sports Basketball) that tries to write in audio data (using the range `$DFF0A0` to `$DFF0D0`) but for some reason (bad programming), the index is sometimes (not always) bogus

```
MOVEA.L #$00DFF0A0,A0        ;004e78: 207c00dff0a0  load custom address in A0
MOVE.W  $0008(A5),D0         ;004e80: 302d0008      audio channel 0-3
LSL.W   #4,D0                ;004e84: e948          shifting (mul by 16)
MOVE.L  -$346E(A4),(A0,D0.W) ;004e86: 21accb920000  write to register
```

if `D0` is greater than 3, then the write to `(A0,D0.W)` is way out of bounds. In my case it writes to `$DFC5A0`, because after shifting `D0` is `$D500`. It also depends on the memory location of the memory expansion (using only chip memory doesn't trigger the bug).

I know that the Amiga addressing system has masks for custom registers and CIAs, and maybe it will actually write to the correct address (I doubt it with `$D50` as a base value for the channel index...), but if I fix the issue by removing the write when the index is out of range, maybe that the sound won't work, whereas it works with that bogus address.

For instance, if I write something to `$DFC09A` it actually has an effect on `$DFF09A` (INTENA, easier to check with this particular register which has a read-only counterpart) but if I write to `$DFC59A` it has no effect on INTENA.

I don't want to leave that bogus address as is, because it violates the memory layout. Is there a formula to mask this address and get back in the `$DFF0A0 - $DFF0D0` range ?

Comment: What is your program doing with the low 4 bits of DMACON? **Maybe** you can safely ignore audio channels that aren't even used?

Comment: DMACON audio is enabled at the time of the wrong access.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*note: I'm answering my own question after more research and experimentation.*

The `$DFF000` base is the custom chip register base address *recommended by Commodore*.

But many other base addresses work. Some address lines select the custom chip base, and some are ignored.

The custom chip address area is `DF0000-DFFFFF` so any base like `$DFx000` works.

This is confirmed by doing some tests on WinUAE emulator, which is very faithful of those aspects, and which has the interesting ability of being able to *read* what's written in the register using its internal debugger.

So if I write `$12345678` in `$DFC0A0` for instance, `$12345678` will appear in `$DFF0A0` when reading custom registers (using the emulator): `$DFC000` is as good as `$DFF000` as a custom chip base address, and some games (for instance Curse of Ra) use alternate custom base addresses (Curse of Ra uses `$DFE000`), maybe to confuse hackers, or just to be original.

Now when I write a 32-bit value to `$DFC5A0` (real-life example), the address translates to custom registers `$1A0` and `$1A2` which are color registers 16 and 17 (`$5A0` is masked to `$1A0`, there are only $100 16 bit custom registers, any higher bit is ignored), so in that case, the audio register isn't written, color registers are written instead, so there's really a bug in the sound routine.

Now why doesn't it have an effect of the visuals? Because writing to color registers has usually no effect: most copperlists overwrite those at each start of the beam, every 20ms in PAL. It can be noticeable for the background color (background would briefly flash) but for foreground colors it would be barely visible or even invisible.

So now I had to decide if I perform no action in that case (like the original game) or if I mask the value to select a valid audio channel and see if it changes the sound, and maybe correct a long-term bug in the game.

I ended up just masking the value of the register so it was always valid

```
MOVE.W  $8(A5),D0 ; original code
and.w   #3,d0     ; fix 0-3 only
```

when the left player wins the tipoff, the sound is played properly.

Comment: What did you do in the end? NOP or select a valid audio channel? Did either change make an visible/audible change to the game?

Comment: good point, I have to check as I don't remember. Will edit when I have checked